# JS Callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, callback, timeout

I have a diagram containing a lot of data. There is a function to relayout this diagram but this takes 2 up to 3 seconds. So I want to show a spinner while "loading".

Relayout function with callback:

```
    self.zoomOut = function (callback) {
        Plotly.relayout(_plotlyDiagram, {
            xaxis: {
                showgrid: true,
                zeroline: false,
                range: [-1, _diagramMaxX],
                fixedrange: true,
            }
        });
        callback();
    }
```

zoom-Function triggered by the button:

```
_$relayoutButton.on('click', function(){
    self.showSpinner();
    mainHandler.zoomOut(
        function callback(){
            self.hideSpinner();
        }  
    );
})
```

And this is what happens: There is just the relayout of the plotly diagram but no spinner is displayed. When I used callbacks with AJAX everythink was ok, so I don't no where the mistake is.

Also tried something like this:

```
// Show spinner
setTimeout(() => {
    // Do something and wait for it
} ,0);
// Hide Spinner
```

But it seems to me that this works completly random. Sometimes the spinner is shown, sometimes the spinner isn't shown - and it doesnt depend on the diagram's data size, it is just not shown. But like I said; when I use this (hide/show spinner) with AJAX, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Plotly.relayout` returns a Promise, it's not a synchronous function.

Following will work fine:

```
self.zoomOut = function (callback) {
        Plotly.relayout(_plotlyDiagram, {
            xaxis: {
                showgrid: true,
                zeroline: false,
                range: [-1, _diagramMaxX],
                fixedrange: true,
            }
        }).then(()=>{callback()})
    }
```

=================================================

Edit: Promisified version:

```
mainHandler.zoomOut = function (callback) {
    return Plotly.relayout(_plotlyDiagram, {
        xaxis: {
            showgrid: true,
            zeroline: false,
            range: [-1, _diagramMaxX],
            fixedrange: true,
        }
    });
}


_$relayoutButton.on('click', function(){
    self.showSpinner();
    mainHandler.zoomOut()
        .then(()=>{
            self.hideSpinner();
        })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me. No spinner is displayed when I call the zoomOut function this way `_$relayoutButton.on('click', function(){
    self.showSpinner();
    mainHandler.zoomOut(
        function callback(){
            self.hideSpinner();
        }  
    );
})`

Comment: You mean my solution isnt working? Are you  gettin any errors?

Comment: Sry, did not check browser console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Plotly.relayout.then

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why. Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Check out promisfied version. Let me know of any errors.

Comment: Get two errors: 1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined 2) Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: In promisified version, I am not even calling `callback()`. You can't get second error! Also, why are you calling `mainHandler.zoomOut()` instead of `self.zoomOut`. Is self === mainHandler?

Comment: Sry, this was another function I tested. No self !== mainHandler. I am using two "classes" buttonHandler - where the the relayout function should be triggered and the mainHandler (has zoomOut function).

Comment: ok. Change `mainHandler.zoomOut` as I have shown in promisfied version and try

Comment: There is no error. It seems to me that there is no way to realize this with plotly. The spinner is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me. With other solutions it was not possible to display anything before the plotly call.

```
    function changeZoom(){
        // Start loading animation
        showSpinner(); 
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                // Call function to relayout diagram
                relayoutDiagram();
            });
        });
    }

    function relayoutDiagram(){
        Plotly.relayout(_plotlyDiagram, {
            xaxis: {
                showgrid: true,
                zeroline: false,
                range: [-1, _diagramMaxX],
                fixedrange: true,
            },
        }).then(function () {
            // End loading animation
            hideSpinner();
        });
    }
```